# JS Module export import

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules

```
import * as VipCardM from './profession/vipCard/component'
export import VipCard = VipCardM;
```

The code is valid. What's the meaning of `export import xxx = xxx`?

IN TYPE-SCRIPT.

Comment: What makes you assume this code is valid?

Comment: That's quite definitely a syntax error. Are you using pure EcmaScript?

Comment: any chance you are working with typescript?

Comment: @FelixKling Compiled success and works fine in ts.

Comment: The `import x = y` part seems to be a special syntax for typescript: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require. It appears surprising that it can be combined with `export` though.

Comment: @FelixKling that link actually discusses a separate feature. This is actually called an [alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#aliases). The `import export` syntax is a shorthand. Specifically, `export import id= ns.id, for `import id = ns.id; export { id };`. The alias `id` creates an identifier in all of the declaration spaces that `ns.id` exists in: value, type, and namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It compiled to `export var VipCard = VipCardM;`  by tsc.